# Flume NullPointerExceptions on checkpoint

Tags: stream, nullpointerexception, flume

I've setup a file to file source/sink , just as a test of basic flume functionality.

Im currently using the "exec" source, with the command being "tail -F mytmpfile".

In my script, I continuously echo "....." >> mytmpfile , so that the tail command constitutes a stream.

However, I've started seeing the following exception in the flume logs:

> java.lang. IllegalStateException: Channel closed [channel=c1]. Due to
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.createTransaction(FileChannel.java:353)
>       at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicChannelSemantics.getTransaction(BasicChannelSemantics.java:122)
>       at org.apache.flume.sink.RollingFileSink.process(RollingFileSink.java:183)
>       at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
>       at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.writeCheckpoint(Log.java:895)
>       at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:406)
>       at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:303)
>       at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:236)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>       ... 1 more

Any thoughts on where this NullPointerException is coming from?  It appears from scanning the code that maybe it related to a missing folder or directory.  But I cant find the exact line on the git hub branches.

This is using apache-flume-1.3.1.23-...

Comment: It seems that the error comes from "file" channel (http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#file-channel), not "exec" source. Its code is here: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=tree;f=flume-ng-channels/flume-file-channel/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/channel/file;h=76ec0ada7eb9640a2589d932319369c921002e4a;hb=77b5d2885fecb3560a873bd89f49cbac8a010347. Why don't you use standard "memory" channel (http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#memory-channel)? Could you show your config?

Comment: The source above helped me realize that the error was in my configuration file, which want referencing the channels correctly

Comment: I've ironed out a lot of these kind of problems through remote debugging- try adding `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=xxxx,suspend=n` to the JVM flags in `flume-env-sh`.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've had problems with file channels, and they've normally boiled down to two problems:

1) If you're running multiple agents on the same box, make sure you configure them to have separate `dataDirs` and `checkpointDir`.

2) On Linux boxes, check that your tmpfs isn't near its capacity. If it's getting full, flume will complain. Try stopping the flume agent, unmount tmpfs, enlarge it, remount and restart the agent.

Comment: 3) mistypes in the  configuration file

Comment: 4) you may also consider purging data from both dataDirs and checkpointDir if they happen to get out of sync. But be warned this could lead to dataloss if your data source can't resubmit.